# shiny app "expr_sub" is missing error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Here is the code for my shiny app:

## ui.r

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",id="main",
tabPanel
(
    "Select Data range",
    sidebarLayout
    (
        sidebarPanel
        (
            selectInput("select_sector", label = h3("Select Sector"),choices = list("Sector 1" = 1, "Sector 2" = 2,"Sector 3" = 3), selected = 1),br(),
            dateRangeInput("dates_range_input", label = h3("Select Date range")),br(),
            actionButton("action_proceed1", label = "Proceed to select resolution")
        ),
        mainPanel(tableOutput("first"))
    )
),
tabPanel
(
    "Select Resolution",
    sidebarLayout
    (
        sidebarPanel
        (
            numericInput("XGRID", label = h3("Select X-Grid Size"), value = 2),br(),
            numericInput("YGRID", label = h3("Select Y-Grid Size"), value = 2),br(),
            numericInput("outlier_removal", label = h3("Outlier Removal"), value = 2),br(),
            numericInput("frequency", label = h3("Frequency"), value = 2),br(),
            actionButton("action_proceed2", label = "Proceed to Service Parameters")
        ),
        mainPanel("Here will be the image for marketing purpose")
    )
)
))
```

## server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    output$first <- renderTable
    ({
        data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)

    })

   observe({
   if (input$action_proceed1>0) {
   updateTabsetPanel(session, "main", selected = "Select Resolution")
   } 
   })
   })
```

I was expecting the output as the data frame defined but receiving an unexpected error:

```
 argument "expr_sub" is missing, with no default
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here. I was going to put there a data set using input variables but receiving teh same error that's why for the sake of simplicity I replaced the data frame.

Comment: You have a typo. `output$first <- renderTable\n({` should be `output$first <- renderTable({`

Comment: Thanks very much jdharrison that just took me one hour to search over web but now i see why i couldn't see even the error replicating over web a lot i just deleted some spaces before (}and it fixes that, still i can't see the /n in my text editor (notepad++) how are you able to see it?
I write for loops etc in R using same format always putting newline before loop start bracket. Why did this failed at this shiny app?

Comment: The `\n` is just me indicating that you have a newline. Otherwise I would need to post as an answer. Currently `output$first` is being assigned the function `renderTable` rather then the function evaluated with the content provided in the expression that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be useful as an answer for other users seeing `argument "expr_sub" is missing, with no default` as an error message. The error is indicating that you have a newline after your `renderTable`. Currently `output$first` is being assigned the function renderTable rather then the function evaluated with the content provided in the expression that follows.

```
output$first <- renderTable
({
    data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)

})
```

should be:

```
output$first <- renderTable({
    data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100)

})
```

as it stands R is just interpreting the code in two blocks an assignment of a function to `output$first` followed by a block of code.

Comment: My full app is distributed over several panels but i mentioned only two of them here. In my last page i have one action button which is supposed to hold functionality to print one data frame using browser print wizard. I couldn't find a way over web do perform this functionality. Can you suggest a path/package/function capable of said functionality?

Comment: Maybe look at `renderDataTable` the dev version of shiny has support for the most recent version of datatable so you can use plugins that support exporting of tabulated data.